# Writing to csv is adding quotes

Tags: ruby

I have string values which I am writing to csv file in the form of array as -

```
output = "This is a, ruby output"
CSV.open("output/abc.csv", "a+") do |csv|
  csv << [output]
end
```

When I check my file `abc.csv` the row added has quotation marks (") at the start and end of the field. How can I get rid of it?

File output as ---

```
"This is a, ruby output"
```

So far I've tried `tr` or `slice` before saving to csv, but it seems writing is causing it.

Comment: This is "valid" CSV (although CSV is not formally defined) and potentially needed to ensure commas within the field are properly understood by whatever reads the output. If you just want to join fields with commas, skip the CSV library and use `[output].join(',')` instead.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. The code outputs `This is a ruby output` without quotes, as it should. It will output quotes if `force_quotes` option is set to true, but it false by default, and your snippet does not set it. It will output quotes if you have quotes or commas in your string, but you have none. In short, please check your example again; if not, report which Ruby you are working on because something is very strange.

Comment: @Owen: Writing CSV by hand is dangerous and ill-advised.

Comment: @Amadan: Completely agreed - but so is removing quotes from a field that the Ruby CSV generator has decided needs them.

Comment: @Amadan Ruby version: `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]`

Comment: I don't have 2.2.1, but I checked on both 2.2.0 and 2.3.0, and neither of them will write quotes in your example. Did you try your exact example, or do you have something similar?

Comment: @Aniruddha: Please provide a concrete example of the contents of your CSV file. There is probably a non-printable character or comma that causes CSV to quote the field.

Comment: @Owen and @Amadan, I updated my question. I have a `,` in string which is causing those quotes. I'd still like to get rid of it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get rid of the quotes then your output is no longer CSV. The CSV class can be instructed to use a different delimiter and will only quote if that delimiter is included in the input. For example:

```
require 'csv'
output = "This is a, ruby output"
File.open("output/abc.csv", "a+") do |io|
  csv = CSV.new(io, col_sep: '^')
  csv << [output, "the end"]
end
```

Output:

```
This is a, ruby output^the end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Owen. Seems I was fidgeting with useless issue, but your explanation clarifies it. Learnt something new.